# Install SSL Cerificate. Ubuntu 14, Apache2 (comodo)

Tags: apache2, ssl

I am trying to install SSL certificate on Apache2, but it's just not working at all. I tried everything.

I have enabled the SSL module. It listens to port 443.

```
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    Listen 443

    <VirtualHost _default_:443> //tried *:443, mydomain.com:433, myIP:443
            ServerAdmin my_email
            ServerName www.mydomain.com //tried mydomain.com, mydomain:443
            DocumentRoot /var/docs
            SSLEngine on
            #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /path_/server.key         
            SSLCertificateFile  /path_/mydomain_com.crt
            SSLCertificateChainFile /path_/mydomain_com.ca-bundle
    </VirtualHost>
```

I should say I am using a reverse proxy on this machine. Everything is fine but SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server responds on https protocol over its IP Address or you get an browser error? Try to use the following statement for virtual host: VirtualHost *:80 (remove _defult string) and, also, comment (or remove) the line:

SSLCertificateChainFile /path_/mydomain_com.ca-bundle

Did you generate a Self-Signed Certificate for your Virtual Host or you use the default one? Also...I suggest that you follow this tutorial to create a SSL Vhost http://www.bytelinux.com/create-self-signed-certificates-enable-apache-ssl-ubuntu-14-10/ and use the a2sslcert script in order to generate and automatically install a self-signed certificate. Also i suggest that you verify the SSL certificate (.key and .crt files) system path to see if it points right!

Comment: no it's not responding to https over ip too, I get noting from browser, and I self generated the key and crt using open-certificate in Ubuntu. its points right to the file and I also checked the permission.